# Logging generic interface for Backgroundjob

Tags: c#, generics, types, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to log just errors in Backgroundjobs in Aspnet zero.

I can do it with given example in **https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging**;

```
    Configuration.Auditing.Selectors.Add(
    new NamedTypeSelector(
        "Abp.ApplicationServices",
        type => typeof (IApplicationService).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    )
);
```

but when I am trying to do this with Backgroud jobs it doesn't work.

```
 Configuration.Auditing.Selectors.Add(
          new NamedTypeSelector(
              "BackgroundJobs",
              type => typeof(IBackgroundJob<>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
          )
      );
```

It works just specific classes;

```
Configuration.Auditing.Selectors.Add(
              new NamedTypeSelector(
                  "BackgroundJobs",
                  type => typeof(IBackgroundJob<TestClass>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
              )
          );
```

What I want is just log all errors occured in classes implemented by IBackgroundJob<>.

Comment: Your selector to detect if `type` is assignable to `IBackgroundJob<>` is wrong. If you read the answers in the link that I mentioned in my comment, you will see.

Comment: Sorry it was obvious as you mentioned. Thank you it works.

Comment: Do you know how can I get just errors. I dont need infos.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging#configuration

Comment: I read it but I couldn't find specifying just for one specific interface.